# mirror modifier for animations?

Tags: animation, modifiers, keyframes

I'm a bit new so maybe this feature exists but i couldn't find it.

But while i'm trying to animate simple things such as a walk or run cycle i find myself frequently ctrl-c, ctrl(-shift)-v-ing the first frame of the animation towards the end of the animation.

Is it possible, maybe somewhat like the way you use modifiers to mirror meshes to 
 use something like modifiers to mirror/copy your keyframes as well, so you don't constantly hace to copy and paste to update the second half of your animation?

Comment: Its not exactly what you're asking for, but you can save a specific pose to a library of poses and set the rig to any of those saved poses: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/rigging/armatures/properties/pose_library.html

Comment: OP here cant comment because i dont have enough reputation and i used a guest account to post the question but Nghillaz answer solved my issue

Comment: @paul37 if my answer helped you, please mark my answer as "correct"

Answer (score 1):

You can use F-Curve modifiers in the graph editor. Specifically what you would want is a cycles modifier with the cycle mode set to repeat mirrored.

[Here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/graph_editor/fcurves/modifiers.html#cycles) is the documentation

Answer (score -1):

When you're animating a run cycle you can set the end of the whole animation to the end of your run cycle in the timeline. Then press Alt + A in order to start the animation. At the end it will repeat, so you don't have to copy all the keyframes.

[image: setting the ending of the animation]